# how get offline custom location in map android?

Tags: android, dictionary, location, offline

I want user select custom location in map and get Coordinate location selected in android .I do not want use google map . 
How get offline location in map without google map and GPS in android?

Comment: I didn't understand what do you mean by custom location. but if you need your current location you  can get it using **location services** using mobile phone GPS . you need not go online. but if you want to display the map offline you would have to download the map prior.

Comment: please refine your question and be specific about what you are asking.